# Command window through batch script is not stopping after execution

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the below script in .bat file:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%a in ('sqlcmd -S RCOVSVR3742 -d FRK -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT count(*) FROM [FRK].[dbo].[interface_log] where interfaceid = '1F88027F-44A0-4089-B6C2-129E9206E478' and cast(idata_stamp as date) = dateadd(dd,-2,cast(getdate() as date))
and idata is not null"')
do set ColumnVar=%%a

echo %ColumnVar%

pause
```

When i run the above code through batch script , the command window just doesnt stop.

**Options Tried:**

1. I have tried replacing pause with cmd /k and still it did not work
2. I have tried replacing pause with pause >nul but it did not work.

I am running the script from the server mentioned in the script.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for the [exit](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) command?

Comment: We cannot for sure determine your specific issue because the code you have posted is invalid. Can you please confirm that what appears in your question as code is exactly, _(including new and empty lines)_, like your real world batch file content. You have also enabled delayed expansion in that code, yet not used it; do you really need it enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a supplement to my comments, this is what I believe your supplied code should have looked like:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F %%a In (
    'sqlcmd.exe -S RCOVSVR3742 -d FRK -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT count(*) FROM [FRK].[dbo].[interface_log] where interfaceid = '1F88027F-44A0-4089-B6C2-129E9206E478' and cast(idata_stamp as date) = dateadd(dd,-2,cast(getdate() as date)) and idata is not null"'
) Do Set "ColumnVar=%%a"
Echo(%ColumnVar%
Pause
```

Please try the above in the first instance, to ensure that the line breaks, basic batch file syntax or the name of your batch file isn't the issue.

I suspect that you may have named your script, `sqlcmd.bat` or `sqlcmd.cmd`. If you have, the code above will fix your issue. Although I'd still recommend that you also rename it to something that isn't already an executable file name.

Comment: I guess the mistake was syntax-related.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `exit` command at the end of the batchfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the line:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
```

And add at the end:

```
exit /b An error code-Optional
```